# git svn - "Couldn't find revmap" - too long path with repeated directories

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn

I use git-svn to track and work on multiple svn branches using git. I use following configuration in `.git/config` file:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = https://example.com/svn/some-dir/project-name/
    fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/svn-trunk
    fetch = branch/Topic:refs/remotes/svn-topic
```

This tracks two branches, trunk sometimes merged into the topic and **usually**, it works just fine. But with **one, particular svn repository**, `git svn fetch --fetch-all` produces following error: `Couldn't find revmap for https://example.com/svn/some-dir/project-name/some-dir/project-name/trunk`. And, of course, in merges are not reflected in git history.

**The main, primary problem:** obviously, the path is wrong - "`some-dir/project-name/`" is repeated twice. But as I wrote, for in-house svn, this works just fine.

So, what's causing this problem and how can I fix it?

I tried to change configuration to following:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = https://example.com/svn/
    fetch = some-dir/project-name/trunk:refs/remotes/svn-trunk
    fetch = some-dir/project-name/branch/Topic:refs/remotes/svn-topic
```

In this case, the `git svn fetch --fetch-all` command produces following error: `W: Item is not readable: Item is not readable at /mingw64/share/perl5/site_perl/Git/SVN.pm line 153.`.

As a workaround, I use `git replace --graft` (and modify `.git/refs/remotes/svn-topic` file accordingly) to manually keep merge history, but it's obviously hack.

**My environment:**

- Windows 10 64 bit
- git version 2.14.2.windows.3
- svn: unknown (it's not under my control)